# Replacing words with special character in a file

Tags: sed

I want to change the command `\pause` into `%\pause` in all my `tex` files. So I used the following Linux command:

```
for f in *.tex; do sed -i 's/\pause/%\pause/g' $f; done
```

but the problem is that the machine don't take into account the character `\`, so it only changes `pause` into `%pause`.

Comment: also the for loop is not needed, `sed -i 's/\\pause/%\\pause/g' *.tex`

Answer (score 2):

You should escape `\` with `\\`:

```
for f in ./*.tex; do sed -i -e 's/\\pause/%&/g' "$f"; done
```